# Add email recipient to all new Trac tickets

Tags: email, trac

Is there a configuration change that can be made to [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) to send a notification to an email address only upon the creation of all new tickets? If it can't be done through config, a plugin would be the second best option, with source code modification as a last resort.

NOTE: The setting `smtp_always_cc` in the [notification section](http://trac.jpcycles.int:8082/wiki/TracIni#notification-section) of `TracIni` will send messages on all updates. I'm in need of email notifications **only on the creation** of a new ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Does this have to be an email notification?  One option you have is to create a query that will list the ten (or however many) most recently-created tickets.  When looking at the results of the query, use the "RSS Feed" button at the bottom of the page to subscribe to a feed that will notify you whenever the results of that query get updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own ticket listener plugin (or rather, override the default one and tweak it), or write a email filter (procmail?) to remove  non-creation mails.

Answer (score 0):

The smtp_always_cc configuration option in trac.ini will do exactly that.

The one caveat is that it will also send an email on any updates to that issue -- not only on issue creation.  This may or may not be what you want.  See the TracNotification page in the help wiki for more information.

We use this feature in our product at [Akiri Solutions](http://www.akirisol.com).

Comment: The goal is to hook up an email address to receive messages on only creation, not all updates.